# Searching by sku number but some products and new product are not showing using search api drupal 7

Tags: search

Some products are showing by sku number but some products are not showing.please someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You need to provide more details in your questions, or it is rather hard to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to indexing by the search module. You need to run cron in order to build the search index.